Converting EET to UTC ignoring EEST
I have measurements of pollutants.
data = data.set_index(data.index.tz_localize(timezone('EET'), ambiguous='NaT', nonexistent='NaT').tz_convert('UTC'))
This command converts the EET time to UTC. It considers, 2 hours difference in winter and 3 in summer.
But I would like 2 hours difference all year, for both winter and summer.
Thanks,
Dimitris

It might be better to localize the data into GMT+2 or GMT+3 instead of EET.
EET is GMT+2 in the winter, and GMT+3 in the summer.
Pandas infers this and applies these timezones to the dataset, which is why it goes from +2 to +3 difference in winter/summer.
Try replacing 'EET' with 'Etc/GMT+2'.
data.set_index(data.index.tz_localize(timezone('Etc/GMT+2'), ambiguous='NaT', nonexistent='NaT').tz_convert('UTC'))


hi, I have upvoted your answer, many thanks. I haven't accepted it due to + and - described in my answer.

Thanks, I'm glad you found a solution!

Wouldn't data = data.set_index(data.index.tz_localize(timezone('EEST'), ambiguous='NaT', nonexistent='NaT').tz_convert('UTC')) just work?  I see it's name is in the timezone name set for Egypt in https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/time.html

@JeopardyTempest hello, no :

eest in 3 hours ahead i want 2.
it returns error. Traceback (most recent call last):

File "H:\My Drive\PhD\2024\climpact\rest_of_greece.py", line 293, in 
dict_2019_data[str(file)] = dict_2019_data[str(file)].set_index(dict_2019_data[str(file)].index.tz_localize(timezone('EEST'), ambiguous='NaT', nonexistent='NaT')
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3_synced\lib\site-packages\pytz_init_.py", line 181, in timezone
raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone)
UnknownTimeZoneError: 'EEST'

The answer of Rowan was very helpful. But, it needs Etc/GMT-2 instead of Etc/GMT+2 to make the conversion.
so,
data.set_index(data.index.tz_localize(timezone('Etc/GMT-2'), ambiguous='NaT', nonexistent='NaT').tz_convert('UTC'))
